# ¿como puedo hacer que todos los renglones tengan el mismo tamaño?

Tags: html, css

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente tabla en html que funciona con datos de una consulta  mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que independientemente del tamaño del nombre dentro de cada div este se mantenga del mismo tamaño para que no se desfase

```js
$(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        });
```

```css
.x:focus, .x:hover{
            color: #fff !important;
            background-color: #000000 !important;
        }

        /*NavDropdown*/

        .contenido{
            height:18px;
            width:16px;
            float:left;
            margin: 3px;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:12px;

            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        div.contenido:hover{
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: black;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Administra<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Amigos del<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Archivo<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Difusión<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
```

son muchos mas y como comente arriba cada uno tiene su propio tamaño como podría hacer para que quedaran todos del mismo tamaño sin importar el tamaño del nombre

Comment: Simplemente poniendoles el mismo ancho a todos. Lo que no entiendo es porque usas 5 `div` para cada elemento

Answer (score 1):

Bastaría con que le dieras a una de las clases del contenedor de aquel contenido que quieras alinear en este caso en su ancho un "width" fijo. En el ejemplo que yo te pongo he utilizando "min-width"(.x {min-width: 250px}) para nunca baje de ese ancho, pero si quieres que siempre responda debe ser el width fijo:

```
$(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        });

.x {min-width: 250px}

.x:focus, .x:hover{
            color: #fff !important;
            background-color: #000000 !important;
        }

        /*NavDropdown*/

        .contenido{
            height:18px;
            width:16px;
            float:left;
            margin: 3px;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:12px;

            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        div.contenido:hover{
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: black;
        }

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Administra<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Amigos del<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Archivo<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical w-100"><div class="toast fade show" data-autohide="false"><div data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="toast-header x" onclick="" style="cursor:pointer;background-color: #7f7f7f;color: white;font-size: 12px;" data-original-title="">Difusión<div class="contenedor"><div data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-toggle="tooltip" class="contenido" style="width: 17px;position:relative;color:black;background-color:#fff; border:.5px solid;" data-original-title="Total de Archivos" title="">5</div></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Además de min-width también podrías añadirle un max-width para setearle un tamaño máximo y un overflow:hidden si prefieres que los datos de dentro del div se corten en cuanto fuesen a agrandar el propio div, de esta forma nunca cambiaría el tamaño de estos.